# Magento 2 add custom static block on product detailed page next o addtocart button

Tags: magento2, blocks, custom, product-view

I am working with the Magento2, in that, I like to add a **custom  block** on **product detailed page**, next to add to cart button. for that, i wrote the below code on

> catalog_product_view.xml

```
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
                <block class="Learn\Share\Block\Share" name="share.otherproducts" as="shareother" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/share.phtml" >
                </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- for config products -->
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <block class="XXXX\YYYY\Block\Share" name="share.configproducts" as="share_config" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/share.phtml" >
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

I got the custom block values on simple, download product. but in bundle product detailed page I don't get any custom block values.

Then, the **custom block** not only for simple, download and bundle product. I want this custom block on all the Magento product types, so give me your solution **for support all product type**

Then why we need to add the same custom block on `product.info.addtocart.additional` section.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts and ideas.

Comment: Bundle products have a more complex schema (I cant remember where it is located) so find and edit that as well

Comment: for bundle product it will be `product.info.addtocart.bundle`.

Comment: @Pawan, thanks for your support, I tried as you mentioned way, but there is no luck. I found some other way to achieve the functionality, I posted an answer on the same question. it's working well on all product except the bundle products, is there have any other way to get the custom block on a bundle product page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

Create

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Bundle/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml

add following code:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.bundle">
    <block class="XXXX\YYYY\Block\Share" name="share.configproducts" as="share_config" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/share.phtml" ></block>
</referenceBlock>
```

let me know if work

**Update I**

After a lot work, finally I found a working solution:

don't need to create a separate xml for bundle product. You can add following code to `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Learn\Share\Block\Share" name="share.bundleproducts" as="share_bundle" after="customize.button" template="{Vendor}_{Module}::catalog/product/view/share.phtml" ></block>
</referenceBlock>
```

If you look at above code, block name is `product.info.main` but we need to set after element as `customize.button` which is addtocart for bundle product.

Comment: I place the catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml on namespace/modulename/view/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml but still no luck, I like to keep all files related to the module within that module, that's why I placed in module view directory

Comment: could you please share whole code ?

Comment: the below code is I am using on catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
     <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.bundle">
            <block class="XXXX\YYYY\Block\Share" name="share.configproducts" as="share_config" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/share.phtml" ></block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: please see my updated answere

Comment: thanks for your effort. the updated answer working well on all the product page.

Comment: glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

The below code is adding the custom block on next to **add to cart** button to all the product type except the Bundle product.

> catalog_product_view.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
        <block class="Learn\Share\Block\Share" name="share.otherproducts" as="shareother" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/share.phtml" ></block>
</referenceContainer>
<!-- config and download product -->
<referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom">
        <block class="XXXX\YYYY\Block\Share" name="share.configproducts" as="share_config" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/share.phtml" ></block>
</referenceBlock>
```

I wanted to add a custom block on Bundle product also, so is there any way to do that kindly share your ideas and thoughts.

Thanks in advance for your support.

[image]